# SQL Server Row to Column wise

Tags: sql, sql-server

Create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempClient 
(
     ClientCode int,
     ClientName nvarchar(250),
     BranchType varchar(1), 
     Address nvarchar(250), 
     Mobile Nvarchar(250), 
     HomePh nvarchar(250)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpClient 
VALUES (1001, 'Test Client', 'H', 'Maxis Street Petaling Jaya', '0125566789', '0355234678'),
       (1001, 'Test Client', 'B', 'J street','0168899123', ''),
       (1002, 'SUper Client', 'H', 'Bukit Bintang', '01289898', '03232232'),
       (1002, 'Super Client', 'B', 'Klang Road', '0168892345', ''),
       (1002, 'Super Client', 'B', 'Puteri', '016223344', '035222322')
```

I have a requirement where a client has a Head office and multiple branch offices, so I want to display the row data to column wise dynamically. I'm trying with pivot but I'm unable, any suggestions please

Output should be:

```
ClientCode  ClientName  BranchType  Address                       Mobile         HomePh      BAddr1     BMobile1   BHomePh1  BAddr2  BMobile2    BHomePh2
1001        Test Client  H          Maxis Street Petaling Jaya    0125566789     0355234678  J street   0168899123  NULL     NULL     NULL        NULL
1002        SuperClient  H          Bukit Bintang                 01289898       03232232    Klang Road 0168892345  NULL     Puteri   016223344   035222322
```

Comment: What have you tried that is failing?

Comment: Please edit your question formatting the code and being clear what you have, what you want. Show results, errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

i can't completely reach the answer but below query will do the trick i think. You should take the only take the 1 Row_number in query.

```
DECLARE @limit INT, 
        @counter INT =1,
        @dynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
 Set @limit = (Select MAX(countClientcode) FROM (Select COUNT(ClientCode) As countClientcode,ClientCode FROM #tempClient Group By ClientCode)t)
 SET @dynamicSQL = 'Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.ClientCode Order By t1.ClientCode),* FROM #tempClient t1'
WHILE @counter < @limit
BEGIN
    SET @dynamicSQL += ' LEFT JOIN #tempClient t'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@counter+1)
                        +' ON t'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@counter)
                            +'.ClientCode = t'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@counter+1)
                                +'.ClientCode AND t'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@counter+1)
                                    +'.BranchType = ''B'' AND t'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@counter)
                                        +'.Address <> t'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5),@counter+1)+'.Address'
    SET @counter +=1
END

SET @dynamicSQL += ' WHERE t1.BranchType = ''H'''
EXEC( @dynamicSQL)
```